# Setting a matrix to one on a list of incomplete rectangular grid points

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinates

I have a set of data in a text file which shows coordinates of a rectangular grid in size of 81x61. each row shows longitude and latitude of a grid point. Longitudes change from 50.00 to 80.00 (61 Values), and Latitudes change from 30.00 to 70.00 (81 Values) in an order like this:

```
50.00  30.00
51.50  30.00
52.00  30.00
.
.
.
79.50  30.00
80.00  30.00
50.00  31.00
50.50  31.00
51.00  31.00
.
.
.
79.00  70.00
79.50  70.00
80.00  70.00
```

I also have another text file consists of some random coordinates which are from the rectangular grid mentioned above.

I want to create a matrix of size 81x61 with elements of 0 and 1 in a way that 1s correspond to coordinates from second text file.

How can I write the code which does that in Matlab?

---

Example of what I need in a small scale:

Text File:

```
  1  1
  1  2
  1  3
  .
  .
  .
  4  3
  4  4
  4  5
```

Corresponding Rectangular Grid of the above text file:

```
1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4  1,5
2,1  2,2  2,3  2,4  2,5
3,1  3,2  3,3  3,4  3,5
4,1  4,2  4,3  4,4  4,5
```

2nd Text File:

```
1  1
1  3
2  4
2  5
3  4
4  1
4  5
```

Corresponding Matrix of the above text file:

```
1  0  1  0  0
0  0  0  1  1
0  0  0  1  0
1  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Your description of the desired result is a little vague, can you please provide an example with a (shortened) set of input/textfiles and the desired output?

Comment: @timgeb: I edited the question, hope it helps

Comment: I don't understand the importance of the first text file. You can always read from the second text file and get which co-ordinates are present and which are not

Comment: @Nishant: If the second file lack a coordinates from a row like the 4th row, how can I tell that my matrix should have 4 rows?

Comment: Is it not predeclared that the values in your first text file will be in the range `50:80` and `30:70` and hence your matrix would be of the size `81x61` ?

Comment: @Nishat: please note that the values increment is 0.5 not 1.0

Comment: Please answer my question. Is it guaranteed that the Longitudes range from 50.00 to 80.00 (61 Values), and Latitudes range from 30.00 to 70.00 (81 Values) . And hence, your output matrix will always be of the size 81x61.

Comment: @Nishant: For this case yes, and as I can figure out the size of the matrix for each case I can change the code to meet my goal. so you can consider it fixed in size of 81x61.

Comment: Now as you said " If the second file lack a coordinates from a row like the 4th row, how can I tell that my matrix should have 4 rows?"
Now, matrix size is fixed so this problem is resolved , hence you do not need the first text file

Comment: @Nishant: In this case, yes. (I just wanted a general solution, but we can neglect this part)

Comment: In your second example , in first file  second col ranges from 1 to 5 and first col ranges from 1 to 4, this means you output matrix must be of the size 5x4(as per your first example),  but you have given it of the size 4x5 , please check this error

Comment: @Nishant: No, it's OK. In the example, The first text file represents a 4x5 matrix (4 rows and 5 columns) not a 5x4 matrix.

Comment: @gnome Tell me this: In your second text file ,what is the ranges of values in first column and second column and, then Among the first and second column , which one represents row indices

Comment: @Nishant Yes, now I can see my mistake. I edited the matrix. The last number on the second colomn in the second text file should be 5 not 4. Sorry again!

Comment: @gnome just for proper clarification can you please answer my question

Comment: @Nishant: In the second text file, the first column ranges from 1 to 4 and the second one ranges from 1 to 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself found a way;

*Assumptions: The minimum value among longitude values is 50.00 & the minimum value among latitude values is 30.00*

```
%// First column of the files is Longitude and the second column is Latitude
  fr = fopen('second_file.txt','r');
  lon = textscan(fr,'%f %*[^\n]');
  lon = lon{:};
  fclose(fr);
  fr = fopen('second_file.txt','r');
  lat = textscan(fr,'%*f %f %*[^\n]');
  lat = lat{:};
  fclose(fr);
%// We know that the overall size of the target matrix is 81x61
  overall = zeros(81,61);
%// We assume that the total number of lines in the second file is 1000 (don't know if there is a built-in command to determine that!)
  for k = 1:1000
      i = int16(( lat(k) - 30.00 ) / 0.5 + 1);
      j = int16(( lon(k) - 50.00 ) / 0.5 + 1);
      overall(i,j) = 1;
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the the  `minimum`  and `maximum` values in your first file in respective columns are the ranges of latitude and longitude. Also, in both the files the first column is Longitude values.

```
 %// calculating the min and max of latitude and longitude 
 id1  = fopen('first_file.txt');
 A = fscanf(id1,'%f %f',[2 Inf]); 
 long_min = min(A(1,:));
 long_max = max(A(1,:));
 lat_min = min(A(2,:));
 lat_max = max(A(2,:));
 %// calculating output matrix size
 no_row = (lat_max-lat_min)*2+1;   
 no_col = (long_max-long_min)*2+1;
 output = zeros(no_row,no_col);

 id2  = fopen('second_file.txt');
 A = fscanf(id2,'%f %f',[2 Inf]);
 % // converting the values into corresponding indices
 A(1,:) = A(1,:) - long_min;     
 A(2,:) = A(2,:) - lat_min;   
 A = A*2 +1; 
 linear_ind = sub2ind([no_row no_col],A(2,:),A(1,:));
 output(linear_ind) = 1;
```

**2nd approach**
*I am assuming that in your second text file first column entries are latitude and second column entries are longitude.* You will have to hard code the following variables:

```
 long_min : the minimum value among longitude values
 lat_min : the minimum value among latitude values
 long_max : maximum value among longitude values
 lat_max : maximum value among latitude values
```

And here is the code (only considering the second text file)

```
 no_row = (lat_max-lat_min)*2+1;   
 no_col = (long_max-long_min)*2+1;
 output = zeros(no_row,no_col);
 id2  = fopen('second_file.txt');
 A = fscanf(id2,'%f %f',[2 Inf]);
 % // converting the values into corresponding indices
 A(1,:) = A(1,:) - long_min;     
 A(2,:) = A(2,:) - lat_min;   
 A = A*2 +1; 
 linear_ind = sub2ind([no_row no_col],A(2,:),A(1,:));
 output(linear_ind) = 1;
```

Comment: @Nishat: Thanks but your solution doesn't work. As you defined, A will be in size of 2x1 with only two values! I think that you should change how A is defined.

Comment: @Nishat: I guessed what you have intended, but at last it only creates a matrix 111x127 with all zero values!

Comment: @gnome can you confirm that in both of your text files, values in a row are separated by only  a single space and two consecutive rows are separated by a single newline character.

Comment: Values in each row are separated by tab and two consecutive rows are separated by a newline character

Comment: @gnome see the edited code and please take care of my assumptions

Comment: the error is generated when it tries to complete the matrix in line "linear_ind = sub2ind...". (size mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a matrix of size 81x61 with elements of 0 and 1 in a
>   way that 1s correspond to coordinates from second text file.

That's the relevant information in the question. The answer is the Matlab function `sub2ind`([documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)). It converts a list of x, y coordinates to a list of array indices which you can then conveniently set to one.

Suppose you have read the content of the second file in a Nx2 matrix called `second_file` and the size of the result matrix you have given in variable `matrix_size` (81x61). You then do:

```
x = second_file(:, 1);
y = second_file(:, 2);
result = zeros(matrix_size);
index = sub2ind(matrix_size, x, y);
result(index) = 1;
```

Comment: I think you forgot to convert the values in the second matrix into indices as they are doubles with range `50:80 and 30:70` for cols  `1 and 2` respectively.